# zfs ubuntu root,how to boot?

Tags: zfs

I try to migrate my ext4 root to zfs root.
The system is VirtualBox VM
three hd,1st hd contain ubuntu TLS 16.04 with 3 partitions
(boot,swap,root)
second and third hd's are for zfs.
So

```
sda1 boot
sda2 ext4 /
sda3 swap
sdb1 zfs
sdc1 zfs
```

I make those steps

step1 OK

```
sudo echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux zfs-initramfs
sudo modprobe zfs
```

step2 OK

```
mklabel gpt Y \
mkpart zfs zfs 0% -512MB \
mkpart efi fat32 -512MB 100% \
set 2 boot on

sudo zpool create -o ashift=12 \
-o autoexpand=on \
-O compression=lz4 \
rpool \
raidz /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

Step3 OK

```
sudo zpool export rpool     
sudo zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id rpool
sudo zpool status -v rpool
```

Step4 OK

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/oldroot
sudo mount --bind / /tmp/oldroot
sudo rsync -avPX /tmp/oldroot/ /rpool/ROOT/ubuntu
```

Then i reboot(otherwise the next step give error)
and i did step5

```
for d in proc sys dev; do sudo mount -v --bind /$d /rpool/ROOT/ubuntu/$d; done
sudo chroot /rpool/ROOT/ubuntu
grub-install /dev/sdb1
update-grub
```

I disconnect sda,and..
won't boot,not in dos mode(bios)
not in efi.
I miss something?
I have follow this [guide](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-16.04-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem)

Comment: Not answering to the question but I'm puzzled by the guide creating a raidz2 with two disks (which means there is no data, only two parity disks??). With only two disks, the obvious choice would be a mirror, not a raidz.

Comment: Very strange guide,you're right raidz is the zfs raid5 "special" and need 3 disk not 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this guide and it worked for me in a KVM with 3 disks in a raidz1 configuration:

https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-Root-on-ZFS

There were two caveats:

1. I had to use non-virtio disks, or else grub (yes, grub), at boot time, would see only one disk instead of 3. Since I was using raidz1, that was not enough to boot.
2. The other one is that if using disk/by-id devices, you may have to export this variable for grub until [bug #1527727](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1527727) is fixed: `export ZPOOL_VDEV_NAME_PATH=YES`

Comment: The link is broken