# Grub / UEFI on all ZFS mirror drives? Recursive rollback?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, zfs

I've completed the instructions on https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-Root-on-ZFS

Everything works great.  I have two drives in a mirror zpool.  I do have a few questions as I'm not that fluent in zfs.

1. How do I snapshot recursively all file systems and bundle / send that (to an external drive)? My fuzziness:

   ```
   $ zfs -r rpool@someidentifierfornow # create recur. snapshots
   $ zfs send (what goes here?) | gzip > backupfile.gz
   ```

Maybe the second command can be automated with a call to zfs list?

2. How do I restore / rollback the root file system from a snapshot?  Can I do that with the file system mounted (is that the right word for zfs pools?) or do I have to do a live image on CD/USB?
3. I followed the instructions for UEFI boot section 5.5b in the walkthrough (which was interesting as my first experience with UEFI),

   ```
   # grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi \
     --bootloader-id=ubuntu --recheck --no-floppy
   ```

Can I put a grub on each mirror drive for UEFI?  There is a note about this in section 5.5a for the legacy MBR method.  GRUB only works for one drive (tested by booting with power on both drives individually.)

Actually, this looks like the correct answer, and will try it tomorrow:

[Re-initialise GRUB for non-bootable UEFI zfs 16.04 installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826209/re-initialise-grub-for-non-bootable-uefi-zfs-16-04-installation)

Similar question, but not a mirror configuration and references out of date material:

[zfs ubuntu root,how to boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760924/zfs-ubuntu-root-how-to-boot)

Thank you for taking the time to read (and maybe respond)! :)

Comment: Verifying if it works, but for (1) and (2), the following site seems to be working for zfs on linux: https://www.dan.me.uk/blog/2012/08/05/full-system-backups-for-freebsd-systems-using-zfs/  (3) works well for the linked answer at the other question (re-init GRUB for non-bootable UEFI).

Comment: I'll be adding an answer when it all works with a known good solution.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Should your question be considered a dupe of [that one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826209/re-initialise-grub-for-non-bootable-uefi-zfs-16-04-installation)?